# Showing Progressring during navigation between pages

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, mvvm-light, winrt-xaml

My intention is that when a user clicks a button to navigate to another page he will see a progressring untill the other page is fully loaded.

I have found a lot of tutorials about the subject, but all of them use code behind. I want to be able to use no code-behind(if possible). I am currently using MvvmLight with the ViewModelLocater.

I have allready made a dummy grid in my views that can display the Progressring and i have bound its active and visible property's to my viewmodels.

```
<Grid  Background="Transparent" Visibility="{Binding LoadCircleVisibility}" Height="{Binding HeigthScreen}" Width="{Binding WidthScreen}" >
            <ProgressRing Height="50" Width="50" IsActive="{Binding ProgressRingActive}" Visibility="{Binding ProgressRingVisibility}"></ProgressRing>
        </Grid>
```

I can allready display it when i'm getting data from a wcf service for example, but not when the user navigates to a different page.

At this point im trying to do this with messaging, but i am not sure where i should put the message that will make my progressring visible.

My message will always go through this method to set the correct values for the progressring:

```
private void ProggressBarVisible(bool visible)
    {
        if (visible)
        {
            ProgressRingVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            LoadCircleVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            ProgressRingVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            LoadCircleVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        ProgressRingActive = visible;
    }
```

But when i want to navigate to another page there is no progressring.

So the Question is how can i display a progressring while mvvmlight is loading the new page.

Edit: partial solution:

The reason my navigation was slower and locked the uithread was because it had to buid the entire page. I changed this by making sure all the methods and logic is ut into a different thread, this ensures that my uithread continues immediatly and i can display the loadcircle on my second page while it is performing the logic and methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do this without code behind
You can add root panel to the your application and put there custom control. This custom control just for showing/hiding preloader.
And when you unload 1st page(or another event)  you'll show custom preloader; and when you finish to download 2nd page- you'll hide custom preloader.

Comment: Yes, i have read something similar to this but i haven't found out how i would be able to achieve this while using no code behing and the viewmodellocater to "fetch" my views